# Send data between silbing components in Angular

Tags: angular, components

I've 2 components and app-component.ts is the father. I want to send a number from one component to other component, but I don't know how. I've tried with service.

Component A ("transmitter")

```
 export class ShowCompnents implements OnInit{

    numberAttendee:number;

    constructor(public eventService: EventService){}

    ngOnInit(): void {
      this.numberAttendee = 8;
      this.eventService.changeNumber(this.numberAttendee);
    }
  }
```

I need to send numberAttendee.

Component B ("receiver")

```
  export class ShareComponents implements OnInit{

    num: number;

    constructor(public eventService: EventService){}

    ngOnInit(): void {
    this.eventService.updatedEditNumber.subscribe((data: any) => {
      this.selectedNum = this.eventService.getCurrentNumber();
      console.log(this.selectedNum);
    });
    }
  }
```

This component receives the number.

And the service is:

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class EventService {
  constructor() {}
 
  public editNumber: number = 0;
  updatedEditNumber: any = new EventEmitter();

  changeNumber(num: number) {
    this.editNumber = num;
    this.updatedEditNumber.emit(this.getCurrentNumber);
  }

  getCurrentNumber() {
    return this.editNumber;
  }
}
```

This always return 0 in component B, the number in eventService, not the number in component A (8).

Thanks !!

Comment: You don't need to use parent component. You can pass data from child to child. In first component this.eventService.sendNumber(data), in second in ngOnInit just this.eventService.sendNumber.subscribe(x => //handle data).

Comment: I think that's what he already does when he calls `this.eventService.communicateNumber(this.numberAttendee)` in Component A and then subscribes to `this.eventService.sendNumber` in Component B?

Comment: In component A I have: this.eventService.changeNumber(this.numberAttendee); In component B I have:     this.eventService.currentNumber.subscribe((num) => (this.selectedNum = num));  but doesn't works...

Comment: You could try to use BehaviorSubject instead of Subject. This will cache the latest value and emit it to late subscribers.

Comment: I have this, but always return 0. The output of component A is 1, but in component B returns 0, or the number in the EventService, don't take the number of the component A.

export class EventService {
  constructor() {}
  public editNumber: number = 0;
  private numberSource = new BehaviorSubject(this.editNumber);
  currentNumber = this.numberSource.asObservable();

  changeNumber(num: number) {
    this.numberSource.next(num);
  }
}

Answer (score 0):

I think this will work.

**Component B**: remains just the way it is.

**Component A**: this needs to receive the updated data from a service method **`getCurrentNumber`** after changing the value of editNumber in our service by triggering an event **`updateEditNumber`** which hence changing **num** accordingly.

```
 export class ShareComponents implements OnInit{
   num: number;

   constructor(public eventService: EventService){}

   ngOnInit(): void {
     this.eventService.updateEditNumber.subscribe((data: any) => {
       this.num = this.eventService.getCurrentNumber();
     });
   }
 }
```

**Service**: the service needs to implement an event to update the data through all the necessary components.

```
 @Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root',
 })
 export class EventService {
    constructor() {}
    public editNumber: number = 0;

    updatedEditNumber: any = new EventEmitter()

    changeNumber(num: number) {
      this.editNumber = num;
      this.updatedEditNumber.emit(this.getCurrentNumber);
    }

    getCurrentNumber() {
      return this.editNumber;
    }
     
 }
```

Comment: Okey, I've changed the code but don't work... I don't understand why...

Comment: @A.Baes are you getting any error that we can relate to

Comment: No error, in show.component (A), console.log(this.numberAttendee) is 8. But in share.component (B), console.log don't print nothing now. I've edit the code to show you how I've the code now.

Comment: Maybe it's printing nothing because you are printing a variable that is undefined in **Component B** `this.selectedNum` doesn't exist you can use the defined variable above and instead do this `this.num= this.eventService.getCurrentNumber();
console.log(this.num);`